# How to register a route to an external application in C# MVC/IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

Here's the scenario.  I have a website, we'll call it Website1.com, built using C# MVC hosted in IIS.  A web app was created in a completely different C# MVC project for Website1.com and is currently hosted at Website1.com/webapp, where /webapp is an application in IIS with an Alias of webapp pointing to the physical path in /inetpub/wwwroot of the webapp.  This works well, without any issues.

However now the client wants the webapp moved to Website1.com/Users/webapp.  /Users is one of many areas inside of Website1.com's project.  I'm having difficulties getting /webapp to get picked up this way.  Creating a "Users" folder in the directory for Website1 doesn't work, IIS tries to redirect all traffic to this Users folder instead of routing it to the code.  Obviously without an actual folder for /Users I can't create an IIS Application for the webapp.  The closest I've gotten is inside the Areas folder of the project creating a webapp folder on the same level as Users and creating the application here, but then the URL is Website1.com/Areas/Users/challenge not Website1.com/Area/challenge.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!